# GridView row in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, selectedindex

I have a gridview which has an asp image-button for deleting a row. I implemented a fade effect while the row is being deleted; that's working fine. My problem is the fade effect works always - whether the user has clicked ok or cancel. I want the fade effect only when user has clicked ok for the confirm box. I am stuck. Below is my code for the fade effect.

```
function removeRow() {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this comment?")) {
                $("#dnn_BlogCommentManager1_grdBlogComments td: input[type='image']").click(function () {
                    $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
                    if ($(this).hasClass("imgDelete")) {
                        $tr.css("background-color", "red");
                        $tr.fadeOut(500, function () { $tr.remove() });
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I know I cannot place the click event inside the function, but I don't know how I can get the clicked row inside the `removeRow` function.

Comment: How is removeRow called if it is not already bound to the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Adam, its done instead of the if condition outside the qquery click event, i put it inside the click event like below

```
   $(\"#dnn_BlogCommentManager1_grdBlogComments td: input[class='imgDelete']\").click(function () {
       $tr = $(this).closest(\"tr\");
  if (confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete this comment?\")) {
        if ($(this).hasClass(\"imgDelete\")) {
             $tr.css(\"background-color\", \"red\");
              $tr.fadeOut(500, function () { $tr.remove() });
          }
      }
      else {
       return false;
      }
  });
```

Anyways thanks for showing your concern... thanks a lot.